# .range(ContRow&":"&ContRow).entirerow.Delete

Tags: excel, vba

This is the line I'm having trouble with:

```
.range(ContRow&":"&ContRow).entirerow.Delete
```

This is the macro:

```vb
Sub Cont_Delete()
    With Sheet1
        If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this record?", vbYesNo, "Delete 
         Record") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
        If .Range("B3").Value = Empty Then Exit Sub
        ContRow = .Range("B3").Value.Range(ContRow&":"&ContRow).EntireRow.Delete.Range("D18").Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Error message:

```
Syntax error and compile error expected: list separator or )
```

Answer (score 0):

you are concatenating code lines

you most probably need this:

```
Sub Cont_Delete()
    With Sheet1
        If IsEmpty(.Range("B3")) Then Exit Sub
        If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this record?", vbYesNo, "Delete Record ") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
        .Rows(.Range("B3").Value).EntireRow.Delete
        .Range("D18").Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you! it works like a charm! i owe you a lot! :)